# Grub options are not visible on booting on Samsung ATIV Book 9 Lite running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, 14.04, uefi, samsung

I've managed to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my new Samsung ATIV Book 9 Lite ultrabook. After updating some configuratiosn in the UEFI installation was very easy. The only questions and issue I believe I'm still experience is when booting.

I believe when the laptop would be displaying the grub boot options I see the following. There is a black screen with a purple border of 10px around the screen. I'd like to know how I can update my system so that I see the grub boot manager.

I've run these commands:

sudo cat /etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

The command was not possible, `sudo efibootmgr`.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the output of `sudo cat /etc/default/grub` and `sudo efibootmgr`?

Comment: Do I need to install `efibootmgr` with apt-get?

Comment: I would use the answer proposed by Subheer.  The file that grub.cfg is generated from (`/etc/default.grub`) had the hidden timeout set.  You only need `efibootmgr` if you have Ubuntu installed in UEFI mode.  Considering `efibootmgr` is not present, you are most likely in BIOS mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my issue here, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226337.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal (ctrl+Alt+T) and run

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Edit the file put `#` before the `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` and change:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
```

Save the file (not 'save as') and close it.

Now go back to terminal and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot and see.

Comment: I've tried do as you've suggested but it has solved my issue. Would installing `efibootmgr` help?

Comment: I get the following output when I run `sudo update-grub` after making the changes.

`Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.`
`Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic`
`Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-24-generic`
`Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf`
`Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin`
`done`

Comment: Try installing grub-customiser

Comment: What will grub-customiser let me do?

Comment: It will let you change the grub options